# How to log exceptions with structured arguments in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, structured-data

I can't find a consistent way to log exceptions in my .NET Core microservice.
Informational messages logging guidelines are simple (Microsoft.Extension.Logging is used):

```
_logger.LogInformation($"Reading file {path}..."); // bad
_logger.LogInformation("Reading file {Path}...", path); // good
```

The benefit of the second variant is structured information: by using a clever log event router (like Serilog with RenderedCompactJsonFormatter) the path is written as separate property of the log event.

Things are going worse with **errors** logging. The requirements are obvious:

1. Errors are implemented as exceptions.
2. An error is logged in the catch block where it is handled.
3. Each error is logged in a structured form.

So, I'd expect the error reporting to look like

```
throw new MyException("Failed to read file {Path}", path);
```

and error logging - like

```
catch(MyException e)
{
  _logger.LogError(e, "Processing error");
}
```

LogError method here logs the complete error description, but it is not structured: the path is not added as a property.
I tried to make MyException hold the message template and the arguments, but there are 2 problems with this approach:

1. How to render the exception message based on a template with named arguments?
2. An argument may be disposed when an exception is processed in a catch block.

Please tell me how you deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions in .NET don't support structured parameters like that. Since you are using custom exceptions, you could add this functionality to your own exception class.

For example:

```cs
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public object[] Props { get; }

    public MyException()
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    // Add custom "props" parameter to your exception class
    public MyException(string message, params object[] props)
        : base(message)
    {
        Props = props;
    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Now in your code you could do something like this:

```cs
try
{
    var file = "image.png";
    var path = "./my/path/";
    throw new MyException("Failed to read file '{file}' in path '{path}'", file, path);
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    _logger.LogError(e, e.Message, e.Props);
}
```

If you look at your logs (I'm using InvisionLog here), then you should see that it is structured.

I think this is the only way to catch your exceptions and log them in a structured manner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, my approach was very similar. But it does not solve problems 1 and 2 at the bottom of my question.  I haven't found a better way to render messages than replacing named placeholders with numbered ones, but it's incompatible with the Serilog {@name} syntax.

Comment: @vivendi i dont find the right documentation in invisionlog.com to access the logs from my internal web server !  im stuck. With Seq, i can add my internal url server in the appsetting.conf  but with invisionlog i dont see it in the config file example. Any idea how ?

Comment: @Kivo I'm not the owner of invisionlog, I'm just a user. I'm also not sure what you mean? You install one of their Nuget packages. The InvisionLog Serilog package for example, and add the configuration in your Startup.cs and you should be able to see the Logs from  their online dashboard. You can't host the logs offline. All is stored in the cloud so you don't have to install anything on your server(s).

Comment: @Vivendi i have contacted the team support and they gaved me the same answer as yours so i  got my answer. My server is an intranet and cannot have access to the internet. I will have to find another tool like seq or stay with seq then. Thanks